# Cloned div with sortable table allows dragging but not sorting

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a web form in when I need to add div blocks dynamically.  Within the div blocks lives a sortable table of items.  I am doing the add of the div and it's children by calling clone() on the last div, fixing up the inputs as needed (code admitted since its irrelavent to the test). and appending the newly cloned div to the last div's parent.  However, no matter what I try, I am unable to get the newly cloned div w/ child table to be sortable like it's predicessor.

I have setup the [following test](http://jsfiddle.net/E2tTK/) showing the problem at jsFiddle.

And for those not able to see jsFiddle, here is the relavent bits to try:

The HTML part:

```
<div>
    <div class="inner">
        <input name="one" value="something" />
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>First</td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="row1" value="1" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Second</td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="row2" value="2" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Third</td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="row3" value="3" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Fourth</td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="row4" value="4" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <br/>
</div>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Add" />
```

And the jQuery part

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.inner table tbody').sortable({
        stop: function () { /* Some code to reset the row numbers */
        }
    });

    $('#button').click(function(event) {
        var newInnerDiv = $('div.inner:last').clone(true,true);

        // clean up the inputs

        // Append the new Item Type to the parent of the existing one
        $(newInnerDiv).appendTo($('div.inner:last').parent());

        // renumber inputs

        // Even if I make this re-sortable, the new table doesn't work
        $(newInnerDiv).sortable();
    });
});
```

Is there some way to re-apply the sortability of the newly cloned table?  We are using jQuery 1.7.1 and jQuery UI 1.8.13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clone the table *without* data and events (cloning it with events means that the rows of your new table want to be sorted into the *old* table), then make the table sortable instead of the original div. (You can also chain your methods for convenience.)

```
    var newInnerDiv = $('div.inner:last').clone(false,false)
        .appendTo($('div.inner:last').parent())
        .find('tbody').sortable();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/2d6G9/

You can also replace `.appendTo($('div.inner:last').parent())` with `.insertAfter('div.inner:last')` for [nearly the same result](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/2d6G9/2/) (you have a `<br>` in there as well, which changes position depending on which code you use).

Comment: That makes sense. In my "real" code, I have a bunch of buttons in the table to remove rows, and I was sort of hoping to preserve their click events, which is why I went the clone route instead of just building the DOM and adding it. But, I guess if I want the sorting to work with the clone I have to take the good with the bad.

Comment: If you [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) those click events to a common parent element, they'll be attached to the parent instead and you don't need to worry about cloning them: `$('common-parent-selector').on('click','button-selector',function(){...})`

Comment: jQuery never ceases to amaze me :).